# unable to connect to PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: configuration, postgresql, connection

I installed postgresql 8.4.x on Ubuntu server 10.04 on x386 box. I also did the following steps

**edited /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf** and 
added the following lines

listen_addresses = ‘*’
password_encryption = on

**edited /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf**
and added 
host all all y.y.y.y 255.255.255.0 md5

I **enabled the firewall to open port 5432** and checked to see if the port is open bye typing
sudo ufw status and I could see that 5432 is open.

Then finally I restarted the postgres service.

However, from my PC, I am not able to connect to the postgresql server -- I get the error as "*could not connect to server: Connection refused . Is the server running on host x.x.x.x and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432 ?*".

What can I do to ensure that postgres can listen to my connections ?

Thank you,

BR,
~A

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I actually did not save my changes to postgresql.conf which meant that the server was only listening to localhost interface and not to other interfaces. Duh!